# python subplot text location when ylim is different

Tags: python, pandas, subplot

I want to add text in multiple subplot figures when those figures have different ylim.

I want to add text exact same location in each subplot.

However, the problem is each subplot has a different range of y-axis.

[image]

My Original Code is this,

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,4)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,5)
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,6)

sns.lineplot( x = 'date',
            y = 'wage',
            data = epi_raw_occ_2018_private[epi_raw_occ_2018_private['docc03']==1],
            label = 'Management occupations',
            ax=ax1)

ax1.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1),linewidth=0.5, color='k',linestyle='--')

sns.lineplot( x = 'date',
            y = 'wage',
            data = epi_raw_occ_2018_private[epi_raw_occ_2018_private['docc03']==2],
            label = 'Business and financial operations occupations',
            ax=ax2)

ax2.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1),linewidth=0.5, color='k',linestyle='--')


sns.lineplot( x = 'date',
            y = 'wage',
            data = epi_raw_occ_2018_private[epi_raw_occ_2018_private['docc03']==3],
            label = 'Computer and mathematical science occupations',
            ax=ax3)

ax3.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1),linewidth=0.5, color='k',linestyle='--')
```

Here is example of my dataframe

```
epi_raw_occ_2018_private[['date','wage','docc03']]

epi_raw_occ_2018_private:
date          wage        docc03
200206         40           1
200207         50           1
200208         60           1
.
.
.
200206         30           2
200207         30           2
200208         40           2
.
.
.
200206         10           3
200207         10           3
200208         20           3
.
```

I am drawing a wage graph according to each Mocc category. However, since the maximum and minimum wage points for each category are different, it is difficult to put text in the place I want.

is there any way to handle this problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: take the range of the y axis times .75

Comment: Thanks. I already looked into it. But, I couldn't write down code to find each y-axis limit in subplots.

Comment: I mean there are multiple possible ways to do it. But I think the simplest would be to take the range of your dataset and then calculate the coordinates with that.

Comment: can you provide an example dataset in your question?

Comment: Thanks @Snake_py. I add the example of my dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use annotations to adjust the display position of text annotations. If you specify a value in the range from 0 to 1, based on the lower left corner of the graph, it will be displayed at the same position regardless of the y-axis value. See here for more [details](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,3,3)

sns.lineplot( x = 'date',
            y = 'wage',
            data = df[df['docc03']==1],
            label = 'Management occupations',
            ax=ax1)
ax1.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1),linewidth=0.5, color='k',linestyle='--')
ax1.annotate('text', (0.8, 0.1), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
sns.lineplot( x = 'date',
            y = 'wage',
            data = df[df['docc03']==2],
            label = 'Business and financial operations occupations',
            ax=ax2)
ax2.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1),linewidth=0.5, color='k',linestyle='--')
ax2.annotate('text', (0.8, 0.1), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')

sns.lineplot( x = 'date',
            y = 'wage',
            data = df[df['docc03']==3],
            label = 'Computer and mathematical science occupations',
            ax=ax3)
ax3.axvline(dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1),linewidth=0.5, color='k',linestyle='--')
ax3.annotate('text', (0.8, 0.1), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image]